# How can I extract data from the Google Picker API so I can render it to the DOM using ReactJS?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, integration

I am using Google Picker API [(npm package)](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-google-picker). This API authenticates user, enable to select a file from the Google Drive, and after selecting it, it logs the data in the console.

Now, I want to grab that file from the console and render it to the DOM. The scenario is to send the selected file in the chat. The code is shown below Need help!

```
import import React, {Component} from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import GooglePicker from "react-google-picker";
import "./App.css";

const CLIENT_ID =
"422770371323-385g839aqfra718os8gfjpts35gj7r4p.apps.googleusercontent.com";
const DEVELOPER_KEY = "AIzaSyBy60QkynXkhEJs6tmSgvayYASb5Tm0Fco";
const SCOPE = ["https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly"];

function App() {
return (
    <div className="container">
        <GooglePicker
            clientId={CLIENT_ID}
            developerKey={DEVELOPER_KEY}
            scope={SCOPE}
            onChange={(data) => console.log("on change:", data)}
            onAuthFailed={(data) => console.log("on auth failed:", data)}
            multiselect={true}
            navHidden={true}
            authImmediate={false}
            mimeTypes={["image/png", "image/jpeg", "image/jpg"]}
            viewId={"DOCS"}
        >
            <button>Click here to select files</button>
            <div className="google"></div>
        </GooglePicker>
        <br />
        <hr />
        <br />
        <GooglePicker
            clientId={CLIENT_ID}
            developerKey={DEVELOPER_KEY}
            scope={SCOPE}
            onChange={(data) => console.log("on change:", Object.keys(data))}
            onAuthFailed={(data) => console.log("on auth failed:", data)}
            multiselect={true}
            navHidden={true}
            authImmediate={false}
            viewId={"FOLDERS"}
            createPicker={(google, oauthToken) => {
                const googleViewId = google.picker.ViewId.FOLDERS;
                const docsView = new google.picker.DocsView(googleViewId)
                    .setIncludeFolders(true)
                    .setMimeTypes("application/vnd.google-apps.folder")
                    .setSelectFolderEnabled(true);

                const picker = new window.google.picker.PickerBuilder()
                    .addView(docsView)
                    .setOAuthToken(oauthToken)
                    .setDeveloperKey(DEVELOPER_KEY)
                    .setCallback(() => {
                        console.log("Custom picker is ready!");
                    });

                picker.build().setVisible(true);
            }}
        >
            <span>
                Click to build a picker which shows folders and you can select folders
            </span>
            <div className="google"></div>
        </GooglePicker>
    </div>
    );
    }

    export default App;
```